# Restricting user access to command with specific flags

Tags: linux, access-control

Is there a way to restrict a user's access so that they can still execute a command, but only with a particular flag?

For example, if I want to allow users to be able to read all files, they should be allowed to run 'chmod 444 [file]', but I don't want them to be able to set any other access level.

Or 'lspci -vvv' shows the bus speed and lane width only when running as root. But, I would like certain users to be able to see that information.

Is there a way to restrict these two commands to be run-able with only these flags.

Comment: see `man sudoers`

Comment: So, the following should work if I add it to sudoers? "%GroupName ALL=NOPASSWD: lspci -vvv, chmod 444 *"